# How to interpret JMeter results and functioning

Tags: mysql, performance, cassandra, jmeter, stress-testing

I am using JMeter 2.13 to check the response time of some queries in MySQL and Cassandra.

My idea is to run the same queries when accessed by 1, 100 and 1,000 users.
(Number of Threads = 1/ 100 / 1000)

When I run the query to a thread equal to 1 the results are very different in Jmeter in respect thereof query in MySQL Shell or CQL shell.

Another thing I notice is that when I run the same query repeatedly in JMeter, results vary always enough.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? The results of the JMeter are consistent to what I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter results include the time taken by the layer and drivers you use for MySQL Cassandra. It reflects more the time taken by an application accessing MySql or Cassandra.

Besides when running your load test, ensure you respect best practices:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Regarding reporting, you can use this version of JMeter that contains a new Reporting feature :

- https://github.com/ubikloadpack/jmeter/releases/tag/2.14-preview-ubikloapack-beta

You can see what it shows here:

- http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/

This feature will be in JMeter 2.14